# React-Redux program returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning react-redux and we are on the part where we just want to bring in a basic object from the back end. My store is currently empty and I have followed the tutorial I am using as closely as I can.

File 1: "reducer-books.js". This file just defines what I want to have stored and passed into the global "state".

```
export default function() {
    return [
      { title: "Javascript: The Good Parts", pages: 101 },
      { title: "Harry Potter", pages: 39 },
      { title: "The Dark Tower", pages: 85 },
      { title: "Eloquent Ruby", pages: 1 }
    ;
  }
```

File 2: "index.js". Here I am taking the Books Reducer defined above and putting it into the state object through combine reducers (right?).

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { BooksReducer } from "./reducer-books";

//Reducer = a function that returns a piece of the application state.
//Just a function that does that. Period.
//Because the applicaiton can have many different pieces of state, we
//can have MANY reducers.

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books: BooksReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

File 3: "book-list.js" where I want to bring in this data. But I am trying to print out the state and it's just empty ;~; so confused.. I like checked over the map state to props function and it should be working?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux"; // redact-redux is the glue between these two!

class BookList extends Component {
    renderList() {

        console.log("hmm?");
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log("HMMM?");
        console.log(this.props.book);
        console.log(this.props.books);
        console.log("HMMM?3333");
        console.log("HMMM?");

        return this.props.books.map((book) => {
            return (
                <li key={book.title} className="list-group-item">
                    {book.title}
                </li>
            );
        });


    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        )
   }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("below hm?");
    console.log(state);
    return {
        books: state.books
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

File 4: app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

import BookList from "../containers/book-list";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
            <BookList />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

File 5: index.js (I guess this file is the "root file"?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

//Reducer = a function that returns a piece of the application state.
//Just a function that does that. Period.
//Because the applicaiton can have many different pieces of state, we 
//can have MANY reducers.
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Here is my console output from this error:

```
bundle.js:21363 No reducer provided for key "books"
warning @ bundle.js:21363
combineReducers @ bundle.js:21448
Object.defineProperty.value @ bundle.js:22554
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:72
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:47
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:40
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:43
bundle.js:21363 Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument     
passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.
warning @ bundle.js:21363
combination @ bundle.js:21481
dispatch @ bundle.js:21269
createStore @ bundle.js:21344
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:21611
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:86
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:47
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:40
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:43
bundle.js:22503 below hm?
bundle.js:22504 {}
bundle.js:22462 hmm?
bundle.js:22463 {books: undefined, dispatch: ƒ}
bundle.js:22464 HMMM?
bundle.js:22465 undefined
bundle.js:22466 undefined
bundle.js:22467 HMMM?3333
bundle.js:22468 HMMM?
bundle.js:22462 hmm?
bundle.js:22463 {books: undefined, dispatch: ƒ}
bundle.js:22464 HMMM?
bundle.js:22465 undefined
bundle.js:22466 undefined
bundle.js:22467 HMMM?3333
bundle.js:22468 HMMM?
bundle.js:22470 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at BookList.renderList (bundle.js:22470)
    at BookList.render (bundle.js:22484)
    at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:11048)
    at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:11016)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:11641)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:14473)
    at workLoop (bundle.js:14502)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:2759)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:2797)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:2846)
renderList @ bundle.js:22470
render @ bundle.js:22484
finishClassComponent @ bundle.js:11048
updateClassComponent @ bundle.js:11016
beginWork @ bundle.js:11641
performUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:14473
workLoop @ bundle.js:14502
callCallback @ bundle.js:2759
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ bundle.js:2797
invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:2846
replayUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:13977
renderRoot @ bundle.js:14544
performWorkOnRoot @ bundle.js:15108
performWork @ bundle.js:15029
performSyncWork @ bundle.js:15006
requestWork @ bundle.js:14906
scheduleWorkImpl @ bundle.js:14781
scheduleWork @ bundle.js:14741
scheduleRootUpdate @ bundle.js:15369
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ bundle.js:15397
updateContainer @ bundle.js:15424
ReactRoot.render @ bundle.js:18728
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:19147
unbatchedUpdates @ bundle.js:15216
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ bundle.js:19143
render @ bundle.js:19202
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:84
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:47
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:40
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:43
bundle.js:12302 The above error occurred in the <BookList> component:
    in BookList (created by Connect(BookList))
    in Connect(BookList) (created by App)
   in div (created by App)
    in App
    in Provider


Visit <redacted>
logCapturedError @ bundle.js:12302
logError @ bundle.js:12341
commitErrorLogging @ bundle.js:12554
commitAllLifeCycles @ bundle.js:14118
callCallback @ bundle.js:2759
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ bundle.js:2797
invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:2846
commitRoot @ bundle.js:14253
completeRoot @ bundle.js:15161
 @ bundle.js:15111
performWork @ bundle.js:15029
performSyncWork @ bundle.js:15006
requestWork @ bundle.js:14906
scheduleWorkImpl @ bundle.js:14781
scheduleWork @ bundle.js:14741
scheduleRootUpdate @ bundle.js:15369
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ bundle.js:15397
updateContainer @ bundle.js:15424
ReactRoot.render @ bundle.js:18728
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:19147
unbatchedUpdates @ bundle.js:15216
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ bundle.js:19143
render @ bundle.js:19202
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:84
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:47
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:40
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:43
bundle.js:22470 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at BookList.renderList (bundle.js:22470)
at BookList.render (bundle.js:22484)
at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:11048)
at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:11016)
at beginWork (bundle.js:11641)
at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:14473)
at workLoop (bundle.js:14502)
at renderRoot (bundle.js:14533)
at performWorkOnRoot (bundle.js:15108)
at performWork (bundle.js:15029)
renderList @ bundle.js:22470
render @ bundle.js:22484
finishClassComponent @ bundle.js:11048
updateClassComponent @ bundle.js:11016
beginWork @ bundle.js:11641
performUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:14473
workLoop @ bundle.js:14502
renderRoot @ bundle.js:14533
performWorkOnRoot @ bundle.js:15108
performWork @ bundle.js:15029
performSyncWork @ bundle.js:15006
requestWork @ bundle.js:14906
scheduleWorkImpl @ bundle.js:14781
scheduleWork @ bundle.js:14741
scheduleRootUpdate @ bundle.js:15369
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ bundle.js:15397
updateContainer @ bundle.js:15424
ReactRoot.render @ bundle.js:18728
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:19147
unbatchedUpdates @ bundle.js:15216
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ bundle.js:19143
render @ bundle.js:19202
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:84
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:47
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
anonymous) @ bundle.js:40
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:43
contentscript.js:58 <body>​…​</body>​
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you mind including the output of your `console.log` statements for us to help debug. Thanks!

Comment: I can help you just relax, Can I see your Root component (Where you initialize your store)? please?

Comment: Erty Seidohl Sorry about the delay! Added it to the post now :)!

Kahlid Ahmada added to the post as well, I believe it's this file at least, I didn't write this and we didn't go over it in the tutorial as far as I can recall :(!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken this is from the Stephen Grider Udemy course, yes? I did this exact course, I can help you.

File 1: This is unfortunately not how to set up a reducer. A reducer simply "listens" for an action and then returns a new state based on the action. We also don't need to use combine reducers for a simple app like this. We can just use one rootReducer. Your reducer should look something like this:

```
import * as ACTION_TYPES from '../actions/action_types';

const initialState = {
  books: []
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.SET_BOOKS:
      return  {
        ...state,
        books: action.payload 
      }
    case ACTION_TYPES.REMOVE_BOOKS:
      return {
        ...state,
        books: []
      }
    default:
      return state
    }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Now we need two different actions for each case statement of our reducer. One to remove the books and one to set the books to the redux state. In action_types.js file declare two actions types like so:

```
export const SET_BOOKS = "SET_BOOKS"

export const REMOVE_BOOKS = "REMOVE_BOOKS"
```

Now in a seperate actions.js file create the actions that will be used with the reducer.

```
import * as ACTION_TYPES from './action_types';


{type: ACTION_TYPES.SET_BOOKS}

{type: ACTION_TYPES.REMOVE_BOOKS}


export function set_books(books) {
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch({type: ACTION_TYPES.SET_BOOKS, payload: books})
  }
}

export function remove_books() {
  return dispatch => {
      dispatch({type: ACTION_TYPES.REMOVE_BOOKS})
  }
}
```

Notice the "payload: books" property on the set_books() function. This will be the main way that we use to save the books to the global redux state through a React container.

Now to create a container that we will use to set the books to the global redux state. Create a container like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as ACTION_TYPES from '../store/actions/action_types';
import * as ACTIONS from '../store/actions/actions';



class Container extends Component {
  books = [
     { title: "Javascript: The Good Parts", pages: 101 },
      { title: "Harry Potter", pages: 39 },
      { title: "The Dark Tower", pages: 85 },
      { title: "Eloquent Ruby", pages: 1 }
  ]

  renderBooks = (props) => (
    <div>
      <p> {props.book.title} </p>
      <p> {props.book.pages} </p>
    </div>
  )

   render() {
    return (
        <div>

             <button onClick={() => this.props.action1() } > Dispatch Action 1 </button>
             <button onClick={() => this.props.action2() } > Dispatch Action 2 </button>
             <button onClick={() => this.props.action_middleware1(this.books) } > Dispatch Async Middleware Action 1 </button>
             <button onClick={() => this.props.action_middleware2() } > Dispatch Async Middleware Action 2 </button>
             { this.props.books
               ? this.props.books.map(book =>
               <this.renderBooks key={book.title} book={book} />)
               : null
             }
       </div>
    )
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        books: state.books
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    action1: () => dispatch({type: ACTION_TYPES.SET_BOOKS}),
    action2: () => dispatch({type: ACTION_TYPES.REMOVE_BOOKS}),
    action_middleware1: (books) => dispatch(ACTIONS.set_books(books)),
    action_middleware2: () => dispatch(ACTIONS.remove_books())
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container);
```

Notice the action_middleware1 property of the mapDispatchtoProps function. This is how we are saving the books to the global state. To actually render the books to the screen we use a ternary expression since it is asynchronous. You can also remove the books from global state with the "Dispatch Async Middleware Action 2" which will automatically remove the books from the rendering to the screen.

When you click the "Dispatch Async Middleware Action 1" button the "books" object we initialized will be passed as a "payload" property to the action and then passed through the reducer where it will be saved to the global state. Once it is saved to the global state, our "this.props.books" ternary expression will be true and the books will automatically render to the screen. And our "this.props.books" is coming from the mapStatetoProps function we defined and our container is aware of the global redux state through the "connect" function we use at the very bottom of the container file.

If not already done you should set up the root index.js file like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/reducer';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';



let store = createStore(
                        rootReducer,
                        applyMiddleware(thunk)
                      )


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
                  <App />
                </Provider>,
                document.getElementById('root'));
```

Before Clicking on Dispatch Async Middleware 1 button

[image]

After Clicking Dispatch Async Middleware 1 button

[image]

That's it! That's all the code you need to get your app working.

EDIT: I left the app.js file to the default "create-react-app"

Here is a link to the repo of a very similiar app I did:

https://github.com/iqbal125/react-redux-starter

Comment: Thank you! This response is unfortunately still above my skill level but I can tell that this is a better way of me approaching my current problems and I am completely appreciating the level of depth and detail you went into including linking your own repo :)!

Hopefully I get to the point in the tutorial where I understand this better to this level!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will get you going:

components/app.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

import BookList from "../containers/book-list";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <BookList />
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

containers/book-list.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux"; // redact-redux is the glue between these two!

class BookList extends Component {
    renderList() {
        return this.props.books.map((book) => {
            return (
                <li key={book.id} className="list-group-item">
                    {book.title}
                </li>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    books: state.books
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

reducer-books.js:

```
const reducer = () => {
  return [
    { id: 1, title: 'Javascript: The Good Parts', pages: 101 },
    { id: 2, title: 'Harry Potter', pages: 39 },
    { id: 3, title: 'The Dark Tower', pages: 85 },
    { id: 4, title: 'Eloquent Ruby', pages: 1 }
  ];
};

export default reducer;
```

reducers.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import BooksReducer from "./reducer-books";

//Reducer = a function that returns a piece of the application state.
//Just a function that does that. Period.
//Because the applicaiton can have many different pieces of state, we
//can have MANY reducers.

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books: BooksReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response :)! I tried adding this import statement on the top of the file and sadly it didn't change the error messages unfortunately. I added my index.js file to the question, I am sorry about my noobiness!

Comment: @KeepingItAnonymous no worries.  Your code had a few problems, I fixed them in the code posted above.  You should be able to copy it into your project files and hit the ground running

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly to solve this issue :) everything is appearing on the screen as expected! I will review the code to find the error locations (one that instantly comes to mind is the const reducer for reducer-books.js).

Comment: @KeepingItAnonymous glad to hear.  friendly reminder to upvote and mark as accepted if an answer gives you the info you need